# Add product.product fields to product.template view - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to add new `product.product` fields to the default `product.template` view, problem is, that I've tried many examples, but none seems to be working.

The issue is that I do have added these fields to the `product.product` default view, (as an inherit view) BUT, that view is only available on sales module, the vast majority of the Odoo's product views are from `product.template`

Does anybody has an idea on how to achieve this on the xml view?

Is it possible at all? Being `product.product` the model ?

Comment: why you add new field in `product.template`, `product.product` is already related to `product.template` , just enable option from sales setting `Products can have several attributes, defining variants (Example: size, color,...)`

Comment: These are a ton of fields for lots of reasons, I can't rely on that, it is sadly the clients requirement, so... I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: so please add something what you have try so far , otherwise it will hard to help you.

Comment: Hi @NeoVe, why don't you create a new menuitem pointing to `product.product` model (and you can hide the one pointing to `product.template`) in those places where you need this behaviour? I think it would be easier than trying to show foreign fields in a view belonging to other model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add those fields to `product.template` model and then they will be automatically added to `product.product` by the inheritance. This way you will be able to show the fields in `product.template` views.

I do not know what is the exact problem that you are trying to solve but when you need to add a field to a product you should think if its value is going to be different for each variant of the product (`product.product` are variants and `product.template` are the original product). If it is going to have the same value (You want to add it to `product.template` view so I imagine it is going to have it) then, add it to `product.template` model.

I hope it helps you.